# iPhone - selection of row in table view only changes that cell, leaves table intact

Tags: iphone, uitableview, customization

I am attempting to create a custom tableview where I have a list of events, and when the event is selected, only that cell is replace with information (or icons leading to other views)

My question is how would one be able to implement such a concept? I know it needs to be done in didSelectRowAtIndexPath however I am not sure how to push this view (or better yet, just a horizontal table view) into this space.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you are askin to replace selected cell with your new custom cell ? rite?

Comment: Yes, however if possible, the selected cell be replaced by a horizontal tableview..if not possible that is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then you can do one thing first create custome cell ,you can make sub calss of UITableViewCell and design as you want ,this is the cell that will be shown when you click on the cell after table view is loaded
now in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when the table row is selected reload tabledata by calling this method

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and in your method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

if your cell is selected return customcell

it will work , i have done it 
take help from this link
http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=482
good luck

Comment: for this, how would you push a tableview instead of just one custom cell?

Comment: pushing tableview inside cell is not a good idea , i guess,if you don't want to push new cell view then use insertrow method for same table view ,you can see the documentation in apple's developer site

Comment: is it not a good idea just because it could possibly slow down the tableview loading? I just want the tableview to display icons to other views, since I do not believe you can put multiple icons in one cell and make them all selectable..unless you can?

Comment: ok for that you can make custome cell and add multiple button and setImage for button ,so now button can respond to your selection rite?

Comment: I am confused. How do I push the Custom Cell from didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Where do you use the [self.tableView reloadData] method?

Comment: call [self.tableView reloadData] in didselectrow it is delegate method of table view remember tableview is object of uitableview if you have inhereted from uitableviewcontroller else if you have created ur own table view then it must be your variable name, and to push custom cell created ur custom cell object in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and return ur custome cell check the link above i have mention u will have better idea,

Comment: you can download code from here http://kshitizghimire.com.np/insert-customuitableviewcell-in-uitablevew-on-row-selected/

Comment: awesome, I saw what I was doing wrong. I tried to use reloadData in cellForRow and I got caught in a loop. Is there a way to implement a slide animation for the reload, or is that just wishful thinking?

Comment: i don't know about that,i mean not done research on that, lol.if you find something let me know.

Comment: I have not found anything, but decided to do what they did in the original link you gave, growing the height when the cell is selected. But how would you go about re-collapsing the cell (or go from custom, larger cell to original smaller cell) when the custom cell is pressed?

Comment: when the cell is clicked use [self.tableView reloadData]; i mean in method didSelectRowAtIndexPath
have you checked the link i gave u last, it is there and when reloadData is called all table view is reloaded so all datasource method are called so now in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can return another cell as you like

Comment: By the way, for the animation of the cell, in didSelect after selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath, put in

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
where UITableViewRowAnimation___ can be changed to whatever, there are some nice ones.

Comment: By the way, if you wanted to go back to the previous cell, all you need to do is create a button the takes up the entire cell, making its background color opacity to 0, and in the button's function, set the selectedCellIndexPath to nil and do [self.tableView reload];